# Why was my "very low quality" flag declined on an off-topic question?

Tags: support, declined-flags, low-quality-posts

I found this very low-quality post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75679688/minecraft-beta-1-7-3-bta-mod-error-could-not-create-the-java-virtual-machine-e).
It's a very long Minecraft error. The user points to "code" that looks like a stack trace. I thought this was obviously off-topic for Stack Overflow, so I raised a "very low quality" flag on it.

However, my flag was declined:

[image: Screenshot of user's flag history, showing the "very low quality" flag was declined.]

The reason given was:

> Declined - a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it

I thought the evidence was obvious. I'm wondering why the flag got declined. Should questions like this not be removed?

Comment: VLQ is mod flag... which generally would be declined on anything readable. Why did not vote/flag to *close* as off-topic?

Comment: The VLQ flag means that the post needs to be immediately deleted. That post didn't; it needed to be closed. You used the wrong flag.

Comment: The "a moderator reviewed your flag but found no evidence to support it" text is a canned decline reason that we have access to, so it gets used a lot because it's quick and efficient (and we have a lot of flags to process). I prefer declining these with a custom reason to provide more explanation, so I use a userscript to do it expediently. The reason is: "Only flag as 'very low quality' when a question should be immediately deleted. To indicate that it's low quality, downvote it. If it should be closed, raise a 'needs improvement' flag or close vote."

Comment: I, also, unlike some moderators, am more likely to indulge VLQ flags (i.e., mark them as helpful) on questions that need closing for reasons that are immediately obvious to me. But this doesn't scale well, and what is obvious to one person isn't necessarily obvious to another person, so VLQ flags really aren't the correct tool to address this issue.

Comment: *"Why was my "very low quality" flag declined on an off-topic question?"* - why did the author of that question choose to put it on Stack Overflow? - Assumptions. Guessing. Doing things without verifying first that it is the right thing to do. That's how mistakes are made.